# How to decrypt aes-128-ecb data in postgresql?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, encryption

I am looking for a way to decrypt aes that was encrypted earlier in mysql and then migrated to postgresql. In mysql I used standard aes_encrypt with block encryption mode aes-128-ecb, but I can't seem to be able to decrypt that in postgresql.

I am currently trying my luck with the `decrypt` function from pgcrypto module of postgresql 12, but I cannot make it to use 128-bit key length. The documentation listed aes-128 as possible, but didn't say how to enable it.

I was trying `CAST(decrypt(cc_data, '...key here...','aes-ecb') AS VARCHAR` but this shows wrong result. Choosing 'aes-128-ecb' results in 'No such cipher algorithm' error.

Comment: I was about ti write l legntthy text but look instead here https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/263851/190821

Comment: It does, I checked it earlier and somehow it didn't work for me on my actual own code, but it does work when I tested is as shown in Your article.
I must be doing something wrong with my parameters, the error must be on my side.
Thank You